# .htaccess to change directory name with querystring

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a url like

domain.com/order/index.php?q=

the order folder no longer exists as its been changed to ecom, so it now looks like the below.

domain.com/ecom/index.php?q=

The problem is we have a ton of external links wanting the order url some scripts and images pull from this url, etc.

How can I simply set .htaccess to still allow the order directory.

I tried this

```
RewriteRule ^order/(.*)$ /ecom/$1 [L]
```

It works only if it exactly matches order (e.g domain.com/order/ , but anything after order it then breaks (e.g domain.com/order/index.php?q=)

Any help would be appreciated. I just keep seeing examples similar to what I have above so not sure if I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: Something like `RewriteRule ^order/(.*)$ /ecom/$1 [R=301,NC,L]` may do the trick for you?

Comment: It just doesn't read anything after order/  (eg domain.com/order/index.php?query=1 )  nothing returned.   However domain.com/ecom/index.php?query=1) returns fine.  Nothing PHP wise is fixed on a set URL so not sure on the issue.

Comment: Show your full .htaccess in question

Answer (score 1):

Use QSA flag

```
RewriteRule ^order/(.*)$ /ecom/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. This isn't working either. This is an older CI application so urls are like  domain.com/ecom/index.php/products/view for some reason it seems to break after index.php

Answer (score 0):

you can do a permanent redirect to a page

```
RewriteRule ^url-string-to-redirect$ http://www.yourdomain.com/your-new-url-string [R=301,L]
```